# Etiquette for self-answering questions

Tags: discussion, answers, etiquette

Firstly, in general, [self answered questions are not considered evil](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer), and it is [something I've done in the past](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/663/106); however, I've seen a few comments on other self-answered questions of late, so want to centralise that discussion here on meta.

So, do we want to reach a consensus on what *our community* considers an acceptable rate of asking self answered questions?

<meta>
Vote for/against suggestions below, or add a new suggestion if you think of a counter proposal:
</meta>

Answer (score 5):

> So, do we want to reach a consensus on what *our community* considers an acceptable rate of asking self answered questions?

I don't believe that any sort of limit on how often questions can be asked is necessary, or even productive. We want good content on this site, and if the questions and answers are good, let them be posted. I see no meaningful difference between a single person posting and self-answering, say, 10 questions within an hour, and ten different people each posting and self-answering one.

And in any case, how would this "acceptable rate" be enforced? Manually? That would place a considerable burden on the moderators and the community as a whole. And suppose a good, high-quality question is asked and self-answered very shortly after a low-quality one (by the same person)? Do we delete the good question, because technically it violates some arbitrary limit? If yes, then we've just taken a step back from graduating from beta, and quite possibly discouraged the poster from contributing again. If not, then what's the point of having that limit in the first place?

The real issue with some of the recent posts is the quality of the questions, not their frequency. And there is already a way to deal with low-quality questions - downvoting. Ideally accompanied by comments with constructive feedback.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion, would be to not ask a question that you're going to self-answer immediately, if the most recently posted question on the site, was asked by yourself, or the most recently asked self-answered question is more less 24 hours old.

Comment: Agreed. I usually wait one day for community try answer.

Comment: Sometimes I will have a problem and after a lot of research I am able to solve it myself. I will then post a question+answer at the same time so that the knowledge is available in one place for everyone.

Comment: @VitorCanova the problem with waiting is that people may leave an answer that isn't quite right or not good enough. If you then have to leave your own answer it makes the situation look worse than if you had just answered it in the first place.